# Checking if event subscription has been performed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I check if an event has not already be subscribed to?

I am refactoring a large application where I have a subscription in `Awake` though there is never any un-subscrition call, so I wanted to move the subscrption call into `OnEnable` and add its corresponding un-subscription call into `OnDisable`, but I am told to leave the one in `Awake` as it is needed...

So, I thought about simply adding it in `OnEnable` thinking that there is no harm in having it both; **is that safe?**

```
private void Awake()
{
    buttonManager.RepeatBetPressed += FinishWaiting;
}

private void OnEnable()
{
    buttonManager.RepeatBetPressed += FinishWaiting;
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    buttonManager.RepeatBetPressed -= FinishWaiting;
}
```

But now I would like to check in `OnEnable` whether the subscription has already been fulfilled in `Awake`.

What code do I need instead of the comment in the following?

```
private void Awake()
{
    buttonManager.RepeatBetPressed += FinishWaiting;
}

private void OnEnable()
{
    if ( /* not already subscribed in awake */ )
    {
        buttonManager.RepeatBetPressed += FinishWaiting;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    buttonManager.RepeatBetPressed -= FinishWaiting;
}
```

Comment: surely you want -= in ondisable?

Comment: you want to say "+=" isn't it @BugFinder ? ^^ That's true Hannes, normally you should rest, not sum the same event, on Disable.

Comment: no, += adds subscription, -= removes it.. surely on disable you wouldnt just keep adding it

Comment: No she means -= which would remove the listener when the object is disabled (Edited)

Comment: (cough she)......

Comment: "surely you want -= in ondisable?" sounds to me that you're telling Hannes to put "+=". If not, I'm trying to say the same.

Comment: (buttonManager.RepeatBetPressed as [MulticastDelegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.multicastdelegate?view=netframework-4.8))?.[GetInvocationList()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.multicastdelegate.getinvocationlist?view=netframework-4.8)?.Contains(FinishWaiting)

Comment: @Lotan im not sure how you take "you want -=" to mean put +=

Comment: @hannes also if you subscribe a second time it will run twice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to use a flag to track the state of the subscription.

```
private bool isSubed;

private void Awake()
{
    buttonManager.RepeatBetPressed += FinishWaiting;
    isSubed = true;
}

private void OnDestroy()
{
    buttonManager.RepeatBetPressed -= FinishWaiting;
}

private void OnEnable()
{
    if(isSubed) { return; }
    buttonManager.RepeatBetPressed += FinishWaiting;
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    buttonManager.RepeatBetPressed -= FinishWaiting; // Minus here to remove
    isSubed = false;
}

private void FinishWaiting()
{
    // If for any reason, your object is still subed but does not exist
    if(this == null){ return; } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the subscriptions are Actions:

```
if(buttonManager == null)
{
        buttonManager.RepeatBetPressed += FinishWaiting;
}
```

And call it like:

```
buttonManager.RepeatBetPressed?.Invoke(); //...to avoid call it if it's null
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to accepted answer what I usually do is simply always unsubscribe before subscribe.

This is possible even if it wasn't subscribed before and makes sure it is maximum subscribed **once**!

You also don't need the flag in `FinishWaiting` when you make sure you unsubscribe correctly.

```
private void Awake()
{
    buttonManager.RepeatBetPressed -= FinishWaiting;
    buttonManager.RepeatBetPressed += FinishWaiting;
}

private void OnEnable()
{
    buttonManager.RepeatBetPressed -= FinishWaiting;
    buttonManager.RepeatBetPressed += FinishWaiting;
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    buttonManager.RepeatBetPressed -= FinishWaiting;
}

private void OnDestroy()
{
    buttonManager.RepeatBetPressed -= FinishWaiting;
}
```

Comment: Thank you; this is a useful and safe way of doing what I am trying to do...